# How to auto reload a tab in Chrome with full cache purge: "Clear site data" from dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, google-chrome-devtools

I use a third party site that display graphs. I need this page to be reloaded to have up to date graphs (and the site does not show it's custom animation for loading data).

But after refreshing, even when holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the data is somehow loaded from a local cache.

If I use the developer tools, `Application` tab -> `Clear storage` -> `clear site data` button and refresh the page, then I can see the website custom loading screen and the data gets updated.

I'm looking for a way to avoid this caching effect, but just for this tab.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

I've tried a few chrome extension that have a clear cache option, but this does not work. The `Clear site data` button that works:

[image: the Clear site data button that works]

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to go to the `Network` tab and check "Disable cache" in the top right hand corner, but I believe this effects all websites.

In chrome, if you have developer options open, then you can right click the refresh button and see options for `Normal Reload`, `Hard Reload`, and `Empty Cache and Hard Reload`. The first 2 have shortcuts, but emptying the cache and doing a hard reload does not.

In summary, the easiest way in chrome is to open developer options, then right click refresh and hit `empty cache and hard reload`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, this doesn't work for this specific application, the webpage is still reload from cache somehow.

Comment: @Thomas I know it's late to reply, but if you still need it I believe that you have to leave the developer options open while you refresh. If this doesn't work for you then I'm out of solutions, unfortunately.. best of luck, I apologize for not being able to help out more.

Answer (score 1):

## <**Google Chrome**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the javascript API had an option to enable the caching on server side.
Switching this option solved my issue.

So the issue was not on the browser side.